# How to create a JAR with referenced Libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I have a Java project which has *referenced Libraries* and is non-executable. How can I create a JAR that contains all these *referenced Libraries*?

Comment: Do you really want to build a fat jar that contains all the references if it's just a library and not a runnable application? Why not provide dependency information in a form that build tools can understand such as a Maven pom? That way any user would be able to pull the dependencies (and possibly newer versions if needed) transitively.

Comment: @Thomas Do you mean it is better to build a jar without these libraries? But if I want to publish my project for example on github the user needs to import the libraries for the project to work. Is this really a standard way? I mean I could do this and if I publish the project I will wirte which libraries you will need.

Comment: Yes, it would be the standard way of doing things. Most projects will be using Maven or Gradle anyway and thus pulling transitive dependencies is as easy as listing your library as a dependency in their project. When you want to upload your lib to github so others need to build it themselves you should also provide a Maven and/or Gradle setup (i.e. `pom.xml` [and optionally `mvnw`] or `gradle.properties` [and optionally `gradlew`])

Comment: @Thomas Do you mean a Maven and a Gradle setupt to load my project or to load the libraries?

Comment: I mean a setup to build your project, i.e. ideally I clone your project and run `mvn install` (if I have Maven installed) or `mvnw install` (the Maven wrapper would install Maven if needed) to get it built (which includes downloading dependencies etc. during build).

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest would be to make it runnable by adding some dummy main method. If that is not an option: Jars are little more than zip files. You could unpack all jars and then repack all files into one. Any zip tool should be able to do this.

Comment: Yes that could work. Or is it better, as Thomas said, that you export it without the libraries. And if I publish the project, I will write which libraries you will need to use this project?

Comment: If you have well known dependencies just name them (best in form of Maven dependency). If you have dependencies that might eventually vanish from the internet include them. In both cases: Don't build one jar. Use git to clone the project file by file